# un issues of MVC + Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many, code-first, one-to-many

I am doing a project with ASP.NET MVC + Entity Framework, it's just like Google doc which can add some types of questions (for example, single choice question, multiple choice question etc. ),this is the Admin's part.

for user part, i dont kown how to save the results which have been chosen by users? for e.g. there are 3 questions: **question 1**, user chose **"A"**, **question 2** , user **didnt chose**, **question 3** ,user chose **"AB"**, and how can i get the results of user? should I use:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index (FormCollection formCollection)
{
   foreach  (var res in formCollection.AllKeys)
```

something like this? but `formCollection` can just get the question which have been answered, so its value is **[0]=A, [1]=AB**,i wanna get **[0]=A, [1]=null, [2]=AB**, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without the code of the view, but I think you should set a default value on your questions options. Depending on how you present them, the default option could be hidden. So when you get an unanswered questions data, you would get [1]=-1 for example.

Comment: i found the solution, answer is : i just save the results which have been done by user. and for which havent been done, i dont save, cause i can do what i want in my controller by the code above ;D thank you!